# Assigning large number of strings (data processing) - Java

Tags: java, json, xml, string

I currently have a processor that runs through multiple zip file and orders the contents (XML files) by date/time.

These are then assigned to a string for example:

```
 public static final String STEP_1 = "XML_FILE_NAME";
```

I have taken out the actual file names for confidentiality purposes.

These are then used in the following code below to process the files and assert against an API endpoint.

```
 Processor processor = getRefinedProcessor();

    for (String d : disciplines) {
        processor.file("ZIP_LOCATION");
    }

    processor
            .format(FileMatchers.TYPE_A.getLeft(), FileMatchers.TYPE_A.getRight())
            .when(STEP_1, this::Assertion)
```

Then the assertion code is below:

```
private void Assertion() throws IOException {
    assertAPI("API_ENDPOINT", 200, "json_file_location");
}
```

Again just put examples in the required fields.

My question is I have 25,000 of these XML files, can someone suggest a better way of processing these rather than setting them in a string.

I don't want to type out a string for each STEP.

I need to run them one by one, so use one XML file, check the endpoint and response file match, then go to the next STEP.

Any suggestions with a few code examples would be great.

Comment: What is the folder structure like for storing the XML files? Wouldn't it be better to iterate through the files in a directory folder of some sort?

Comment: They are stored within zip folders, the code finds them within the zip folder they are located on the fly.